# How to POST in CURL and save header response

Tags: xml, linux, rest, http, curl

I would like to use cURL to POST an XML string as body and save the header response to a text file on the server.

For example I would like to post to address: 
http://example.url/link-to-page

I would like to send something similar to this in my POST request as the body:

```
form_key=lpWNmGj3tGrO6WFq&login%5Busername%5D=USER_NAME&dummy=dqUcSDpPcmKf4mYF&login%5Bpassword%5D=PASS_WORD
```

Then I would like to save the header of the response to a text file. I am not interested in the body of the response. Is there a CURL command that can do this for me?

Kindest Regards, 
Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-D  <filename>`

**Example :**

```
curl -D  headers.txt --request POST --data "somedata" http://example.url/link-to-page
```